# When I saved some element created by jQuery into array, eq() doesn't work for them

Tags: jquery, createelement

I tried to fix it (elem_2) but it seems really weird. Is it any other way to fix it?
Look at this example:

```js
    var array = [];

    var elem_1 = $('<div></div>').css({
        width:200,
        height:200,
        backgroundColor:'red'
    });

    var elem_2 = $('<div></div>').css({
        width:200,
        height:200,
        backgroundColor:'blue'
    });
    $('body').append(elem_1,elem_2);
    //Not work
    array[0] = elem_1;
    $(array).eq(0).on('click', function () {
        alert('elem_1');
    });
    //Works
    array[1] = elem_2[0];
    $(array).eq(1).on('click', function () {
        alert('elem_2');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`eq()` only workes well for jQuery objects and DOM elements, not on arrays containing jQuery objects. And because `array[0]` already is an jQuery object you don't need to cast it again. Just use `array[0].on()` or `elem_1.on()`.

```js
var array = [];

var elem_1 = $('<div></div>').css({
    width:200,
    height:200,
    backgroundColor:'red'
});

var elem_2 = $('<div></div>').css({
    width:200,
    height:200,
    backgroundColor:'blue'
});

$('body').append(elem_1,elem_2);

array[0] = elem_1;
array[0].on('click', function () {
    alert('elem_1');
});

array[1] = elem_2;
array[1].on('click', function () {
    alert('elem_2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I have another problem. I can't use method filter on array without loop.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your code

[image]

just correct it and it will work

```
array[0] = elem_1[0];
    console.log('array1', array);
    $(array).eq(0).on('click', function () {
        alert('elem_1');
    });
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3eqgkuv/)

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind that this now only workes because you extract the DOM elements from jQuery with `elem_1[0]` and cast them into jQuery again with `$(array)`. And this two times. That is pretty horrible usage.

Comment: Yes. But question was not about which usage is beautifull, but about why it doesn't work. There is no particular problem with extracting element and putting it back to jquery, is there? Talking about beautifullness, the whole script is horrible and your version makes it just slightly better but still horrible.

Comment: When you have an `int`, and want to use it as an `int`, are you casting it in a `string` first and then back to an `int` again too? Because thats what you did. `jQuery -> Dom -> jQuery`. I'm not talking about how beautiful your code is, it is just bad behavior. You should always write as most perfomant code as possible and guide the OP in the right direction. And because you *can* do things, means not they're correct! His code is not false in general. He created elements and uses them. I would not do it this way too, but it's not bad in genereal.

Comment: @eisbehr that's not me, that's what author did. Yes, it's _bad practice_ to convert types, but it has **absolutly nothing** to do with what the question was about. It's also bad practice to append dom element to body and only after set up listener - set up listener before appending it to dom, and you won't have to deal with that `array` at all.